# Not all Tailwind CSS classes are being applied from base @layer styling in a React app

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I created a React app with Tailwind CSS and want to style all of my `<a>` links the same way. However, when I save my files only one of the styles is being applied.

**index.css:**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@Layer base {
  a {
    @apply text-blue-500 hover:underline hover:font-bold mb-3;
  }
  li {
    @apply list-disc;
  }
 
}
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        logobg: "url('/src/images/logobg.png')",
      },
    },
    plugins: [],
  },
};
```

Only the `hover:font-bold` utility-class is being applied. All of the other styles are being ignored.

I thought maybe one of my node dependencies was blocking somehow, so I removed any that I though could be troublesome. Here is the list of the remaining ones.

```js
"dependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.7",
        "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.13",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-ga": "^3.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "use-http": "^1.0.27",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
      }
```

I also read that Tailwind CSS purges unused utility-classes during preflight so I added this line to my `index.html` to try and avoid it purging the styles I wanted.

```html
<div className="hidden text-blue-500 hover:underline"></div>
```

So far nothing has worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I applied the steps below, it worked:

- Replace @Layer with @layer
- Set div as a parent selector

```css
@layer base {
  div a {
    @apply text-2xl hover:font-bold text-rose-400 hover:text-rose-600;
  }
}
```